# How to insert and center a Table in Google Docs with Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, tabular

I am trying to create a table and have it end up being centered in the document body of a `Google DocumentApp` using `Google Script`.

As of now, I create Tables using a For Loop and they are created fine, they Just will not center.

I have tried the Following:

**Attempt 1:**

```
var insertedTable = updateBody.insertTable(numberOfTables, objectivesTables[g]);            
insertedTable.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
```

RESULT: This makes one LEFT aligned table then stalls and times out. (I am using a library that I have created and I am calling this function from another Script so I do not get an error message)

**Attempt 2:**

```
var style = {};
style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;

updateBody.insertTable(numberOfTables, objectivesTables[g]).setAttributes(style);
```

> RESULT: All Tables Are created but are Left Aligned.

I have seen this done with Text, Paragraphs, and Images but I cannot figure out how to accomplish this with a Table so any help would be graciously received.

Comment: This probably helps: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/horizontal-alignment

Answer (score 0):

A nasty solution might be to put a placeholder in the doc, center it manually and then replace it with a table.

Comment: "replace" meaning?